# How can i access my ip:my port

Tags: port, localhost

I'm trying to access a specific port (which is 3000) on my server, I can access to `localhost:3000` and I can access `192.168.1.111` (my local IP) but I can't access `192.168.1.111:3000` although I'd added an allow rule to this port in my firewall
So how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is see if anything is listening on `192.168.1.111:3000`.  Try a `netstat -ntl` and see if either `192.168.1.111:3000` or `0.0.0.0:3000` (wildcard) is listed under "local address". If not, you have at least 3 choices:

1. Configure the application to listen on 192.168.1.111 or 0.0.0.0.
2. Configure your firewall to forward the application packets to 127.0.0.1:3000
3. Run a reverse proxy setup (such as apache or nginx) to forward the application traffic to 127.0.0.1:3000

Any of the above should work, but personally I prefer #3 for browser-based apps.